# AWS Java on AWS Lambda Workshop : InvalidParameterValueException: Uploaded file must be a non-empty zip (GraalVM)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I'm testing the AWS workshop https://catalog.workshops.aws/java-on-aws-lambda/en-US. I can't use deploy.sh so I try to upload throught teh AWS toolkit or the Web browser the generated zip and I get : InvalidParameterValueException: Uploaded file must be a non-empty zip.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imdfC.png)

```
024-03-08 12:43:36.874 [error] Failed to run updateFunctionCode: InvalidParameterValueException: Uploaded file must be a non-empty zip (statusCode: 400; requestId: f67e24a6-ed9a-4345-8c51-6cd0d4421dac)
2024-03-08 12:43:36.875 [error] Lambda upload failed: 'InvalidParameterValueException: Uploaded file must be a non-empty zip (statusCode: 400; requestId: f67e24a6-ed9a-4345-8c51-6cd0d4421dac)'
2024-03-08 12:43:36.875 [warning] telemetry: invalid Metric: "lambda_updateFunctionCode" emitted with result=Failed but without the `reason` property. Consider using `.run()` instead of `.emit()`, which will set these properties automatically. See https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-vscode/blob/master/docs/telemetry.md#guidelines
2024-03-08 12:47:33.234 [info] telemetry: sent batch (size=3)
```

The zip is not empty:

```
ls -lah UnicornLocationFunctionGraalVM/
total 15M
drwxr-xr-x 1 S 1049089   0 Mar  7 14:35 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 S 1049089   0 Mar  8 12:20 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 S 1049089 15M Mar  8 12:21 unicorn-location-graal.zip
```

thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to be able to upload the unicorn-location-graal.zip created with the AWS project